Which article should come here?
Had this in a test:

He went to _ prison to give a lecture to the prisoners.

Will there be an article here? If so which one?
My first intuition was "a", but I'm unsure.

You certainly need an article: it can't be "He went to prison" or he wouldn't come out again for a long time! Whether it's a or the depends on whether it matters which prison you're talking about. If the prison has already come up in the conversation, it's probably the. If it's just he gave a lecture in a prison! then a is probably right.

'A' is possible but rather unlikely; if the prison hasn't already been mentioned (in which case 'the' or 'this' would be the choice),, the prison would normally be named here.

@Andrew Leach Nice to see sensible use of a 'comment', by a mod no less, to help OP with an answer when the question should be CV-d.
